# Where to put static HTML is React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering what is the best way to handle a bunch of static HTML is a React app? For example, if I have a navigation bar that only has a search box that needs to be a React component, where would I put the rest of the static HTML? Would it go into another file? If so, how is this best done semantically?

Thank you for advice.

**EDIT** - This is in regards to a mostly static site that has a couple React components in it. Don't want to stuff all of the static HTML into each of the components.

Comment: you probably want search engines to see your navigation, so js might not be the best option...

Comment: @dandavis It's possible to render React code on the server, so SEO isn't necessarily a concern here.

Comment: In addition, Google will render React when crawling, so it's even less of an issue. But anyway, are you asking about a web page that has only one react component? Or a component within a react app where that component is mostly static?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller - I edited my question regarding my app being mostly static with only a couple components